# How to run a Python script from inside of another Python Script?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am currently using subprocess to run a Python script inside of my current Python but it is keep giving me an error:

```
for dir in os.listdir(os.path.join(DIR2,dirname)):
    temp = os.path.join(os.path.join(DIR2,dirname),dir)
    files = [os.path.join(temp, f) for f in os.listdir(temp) if f.endswith("json")]
    for lists in files:
        subprocess.Popen(["python", DIR4, os.path.join(temp,lists)])
```

Above is what I am currently using. 
`DIR4` is the path of the python that I want to run.

Problem is, the python that I want to run can only take one file at a time.
However this subprocess looks like it tries to execute ALL at ONCE.

I want to run ONE at a time, instead of ALL at ONCE.
Because it is running ALL at ONCE, my python that I want to run does not work the way it is..

What do I need to do to change this?

Comment: What error are you getting? Python is going to execute the subprocesses asynchronously, but with different python interpreters. So if you only want 1 subprocess running (why use sub processing then?) you're going to have to wait on each subprocess to finish before starting a new one.

Comment: I am getting an error message that is in the other python.. Because it can not find the file which is already running.. How can I run one at a time as you mentioned? @Falmarri

Comment: I am using subprocesses because that is the only way that I know how to run python inside of python.. but as you said.. it is running asynchronously.. and I don't want that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait first for the subprocess to terminate, before going ahead, I think you could use Popen.wait():

```
...
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", DIR4, os.path.join(temp,lists)])
p.wait()
...
```

Comment: oh my gosh.. Thank you so much... I think it is working fine now...  but just a quick question.. is there a better way to do this rather than using the subprocess?

Comment: you could import the python script you want to execute, and then directly call some appropriate function!

Answer (score 0):

To actually do what you're asking, and not hack it together through subprocess, you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) which allows you to run python code with your own provided globals and locals.

In older versions of Python (meaning pre-3), you can use [`execfile` to achieve the same thing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile).